# Get List of GrandChild in a Map of Parent Id and List of GrandChild

Tags: apex, trigger, map, after-trigger

There is hierarchy of Objects as Account - Opportunity(child) - OpportunityCHild(grandChild)

In this OpportunityChild is a grand child of Account.

I want to create map as  `Map<AccountId,List<lstPSSOpportunity>>`. How
can I write a SOQL query for this in bulkAfter of TriggerFactory.

Comment: Your last line is not clear. You want a map of AccountId to its grandChildren?

Comment: @Reshma , Yes. That is correct

Answer (score 1):

To get the earliest you can do this replacing the field / object names with appropriate values

```
OppChild[] rec = [ select id from OppChild where Opportunity__r.AccountId =:theAccId order by createddate desc limit 1];
```

Reverse the order by to get the oldest

To Bulkify go the other way querying opportunity having appropriate accountIds with an inner query to the OppChild with appropriate order by. Then store them in a collection

```
[select id, (select id from OppChildren__r order by createddate desc limit 1) from opportunity where accountId in :accIds]
```